# How to use if else in cms block magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I want use if else like this code but it not working. Please help me

```
{{if config path="system/config/path" == 1}}
<p> ok </p>
{{else}}
<p> no </p>
```

I create it in home page, menu->cms->page

Comment: what it is showing on front ?

Comment: try remove space in "if config" use "ifconfig" instead. It's just a guess, I am not sure on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be fine if you create phtml file and call that particular phtml file in the CMS block.

for eg.
Your CMS block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/condition.phtml"}}
```

Comment: hi Sunny Rahevar, i tryed, but it not working. i created home.phtml in app/design/frontend/hemmen2/default/template/page/html/home.phtml and add {{block type="core/template" template="page/html/home.phtml"}} in cms but it not show

Comment: Can you please first print hello in the phtml file instead of your code? if 'hello' display in the front-end that means your file called correctly and there is something issue regarding in your code in the phtml file.